# Call a sub from a subroutine in another Access DataBase

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to call a subroutine that is in a database called DB1.accdb from another subroutine that is in another database called DB2.accdb.

I am writing the following code in the DB2.accdb:

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("DB1.accdb")
appAccess.Run "mysubrutine"
```

When I execute the code I obtain the following error message:

> Run-time error '40351': Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed.

mysubrutine is in the second database written as follows:

```
Public sub mysubrutine()
A = 2 + 2
End sub
```

The reference I am using in VBA is **Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library**

Comment: Cannot recreate your issue. Be sure you are using full path of external DB and that subroutine is placed in a standalone module and not behind any form or report.

Comment: Also, first two lines can be reduced to: `Dim appAccess As New Application`. If code is run inside MS Access, there's no need to qualify it with `Access.` or use external COM object creation.